# Why ubuntu uses "move to trash" instead of delete?

Tags: ubuntu, clipboard, move, duplicate

Does anyone know why in the GUI of Ubuntu(and perhaps the other Linux distributions as well) use the term "move to trash" instead of delete? I want to know what was the historic event that leads to this decision. Was it due to the patent restrictions or simply the developers chose it? Since historically, the first version of Windows was released before the first version of Linux and it seems reasonable if they all had followed the same fashion.

Comment: You're referring to the GUI? Which one are you running?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

“Move to trash” (or “Move to wastebasket” etc.) means that the file isn’t deleted outright, but moved to a holding pen of some sort (`~/.local/share/Trash` etc.). The change happened when such features were implemented in desktop environments; the purpose is to allow files to be easily recovered.

You’ll see deletion referred to outright when you request real deletion, *e.g.* with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> in GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that Ubuntu calls it "Move to Trash" because that's what that operation really does, it literally *moves* the file to the Trash directory, as opposed to *removing* it from the system completely (e.g. when you issue the `rm` command).

I suspect the Gnome developers decided to avoid the term "delete" because it's been quite confusingly ambiguous on Windows alone. For instance, if you right click a file and select "delete", the "deleted" file will actually end up in the Recycle Bin. Meanwhile deletion from the command line with the `DEL` (delete) command will wipe that file off your hard drive.